# Sending mail SMTP works with Gmail but fails when I try to send it from my domain

Tags: c#, smtp, sendmail, smtpclient

I'm trying to send mail using SMTPClient in C#.

Everything was fine when I was sending mail using my Gmail account 
using `HOSTNAME: smtp.gmail.com`
and `PORT NUMBER: 587`.

Here is the code which I used:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587)
//mail 
mail.From = new MailAddress("someone@mydomain.com","myself");
mail.To.Add("itsme@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail C#";
mail.Body = "Hello";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
//smtpclient
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new  System.Net.NetworkCredential("someone@mydomain.com", "password");

Boolean MailSent=true;
try
{
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
catch (SmtpException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    MailSent = false;
}
finally
{
    if (MailSent == true)

        MessageBox.Show("mail sent");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to send mail");
}
```

Here are the details provided by the hosting service provider:

1. Secure SSL/TLS Settings (Recommended)
   Username:   someone@opastonline.com
   Password:   Use the email account’s password.
   Incoming Server:    mocha7004.mochahost.com
   IMAP Port: 993
   POP3 Port: 995
   Outgoing Server:    mocha7004.mochahost.com
   SMTP Port: 465
   Authentication is required for IMAP, POP3, and SMTP.
2. Non-SSL Settings
   (This is NOT recommended.)
   Username:   someone@opastonline.com
   Password:   Use the email account’s password.
   Incoming Server:    mail.opastonline.com
   IMAP Port: 143
   POP3 Port: 110
   Outgoing Server:    mail.opastonline.com
   SMTP Port: 25 --> When raised a ticket they also suggested me to use 2525 or 25
   Authentication is required for IMAP, POP3, and SMTP.

But when I replace them using the details provided by my host provider, I am unable to push the mail.

It shows different error messages when I change port numbers (which I was given by the provider):

- port 25: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
- port 2525: Failure Sending Mail
- port 465: Operation timed out

I cross checked every possible thing, but seems I am lost somewhere.

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: it shows different messege when i change port numbers (which i was given by the provider)                                                                          port 25: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
port 2525: Failure Sending Mail
port465: Operation timed out

Comment: Are you sure your domain (smtp.yourdomain.com) handles your email? If for example you use Google Apps or any other third party sw to handle your email, the smtp configuration may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to security settings at the followig link https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and enable less secure apps . So that you will be able to login from all apps.